# How to get openfire chat room Archive messages using Strophe library

Tags: xmpp, archive, openfire, message, strophe

I use Strophe library to connect to an OpenFire XMPP server.

How can I receive the chat room archive of messages ?
I need to fetch messages based on start date and end date using strophe library.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think Openfire does yet support Message Archive Management for MUC rooms yet. The code for MAM user archive support has been merged into Openfire in [May](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/pull/213), but I could not find any reference to support for MUC archiving.

Comment: Can we use OpenArchive plugin for retrieving archive messages ?